# VPN Connection Between AWS and Linode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, linode, aws-vpn

I want to make a private connection VPN between two clouds, AWS and Linode. I'm kinda new to this. Can someone please suggest or help me how can i do this?!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS site to site VPN. And for that you would need

- Customer gateway (linode side).
- Virtual private gateway/Transit gateway (AWS side).

**Virtual Private Gateway:** Use to create IPSec VPN tunnel between AWS VPC and your on-prem/remote environment.

**Transit Gateway:** Use to connect multiple VPCs and on-prem/remote environments.

**Customer Gateway:** A device in your on-prem/remote network.You will provide its information in AWS when you create customer gateway.

For more information please see this link: [AWS site to site VPN - documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/how_it_works.html)

Comment: How can i make Customer Gateway in Linode, I've checked in Linode but there's no option for gateway.

Comment: A customer gateway is a resource that you create in AWS that represents the customer gateway device in your on-premises network. When you create a customer gateway, you provide information about your device to AWS. 
Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/how_it_works.html#CustomerGateway